# Servlets/JSP - What is difference between CLIENT-CERT and Basic with SSL authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, https

Bit confused while reading Web App Security:

Is CLIENT-CERT Authentication is another name of SSL?

Is there any difference between CLIENT-CERT Authentication and Basic Authentication, with SSL?

---

Question arise while reading following information from Head First JSP & Servlets, So please answer in context

Authentication is divided into four parts (column seperated by semicolon):

No. ; Type ; Spec ; Data Integrity ; Comments

1) ; Basic Authentication ; HTTP ; Base 64 - Weak ; HTTP Standards, All Browsers Sypport It

2) ; Digest Authentication ; HTTP  ; Stronger - but not SSL  ; Optional for HTTP & J2EE Container

3) ; Form Authentication ; J2EE  ; Very Weak, no Encryption  ; Allows a custom login Screen

4) ; Client-Cert Authentication  ; J2EE  ; Strong - Public Key, (PKC)  ; Strong, but users must have certificates

Comment: Basic authentication is not related to SSL, in basic authentication username and password are transmitted in base64 encoded format in HTTP header. Whereas Client-Cert authentication is used in SSL channel which provides mutual authentication(both server and client). For client-cert authentications, client must have a valid X.509 certificate with private key.

Comment: Thanks @Deva .....I am not getting What is different between Client-Cert and SSL? Does SSL always required for Client-Cert or does both work independently?

Comment: SSL is always required to enable Client-Cert authentication. Generally SSL is used for one way authentication i.e Server SSL certificate is validated by Client during SSL handshake. If server wants to validate client identity then Client-cert authentication must be enabled in server. During SSL handshake client must submit his certificate for authentication.

Comment: Thanks @Deva.....So Client Cert Authentication is bigger umbrella; SSL is just a way to achieve it. Then it also means we can also use other protocols too for Client-Cert?

Comment: To my knowledge no other communication protocol supports SSL Client-Cert authentication by itself except SSL.

Comment: Ok. So we cannot say that Client-Cert is independent or standard or Generic or Umbrella term, as it is implemented using SSL only. Or as of now SSL only. In future if more protocols come into picture then it will looked as a Generic term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102337/discussion-between-deva-and-fatherazrael).